# should new users be told that anyone is free to vote on questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that some questions and answers have a lot of views, but often only one or two votes. It seems to me that we might get more interest if users were encouraged to vote questions even though they  do not comment on them or in the case of questions give an answer. I would personally find it very helpful in learning what are good questions and what are good answers if more people voted. sometimes I learn more from the down votes than I do the up votes.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, an *obscene* percentage of traffic for mature SE sites is search engine traffic. That means that *most* eyes on your questions after a certain point (the first day or so) are going to be anonymous users who cannot vote since they don't hold any reputation here.

Comment: @waxeagle I understand that we have a lot of search engine traffic, but if you will look at the newest questions you will see that one of the questions has 198 views and 3 votes. are 195 of those views visitors. It is disparaging to see that nearly 200 people have read your post but only a modicum have even told you whether it was worth your time seeking an answer or if your question was unacceptable for whatever reason. At any rate we cannot demand people leave their opinion, but frequent users should give their impression especially if they wish others to give them input.

Comment: based on percentages, all but about 20 of them are. So a +3 with 200 views has about a 15% success rate for direct site traffic. That probably means it's not a *great* question, but it's not totally out of line. I definitely don't vote on everything I read in a day.

Answer (score 3):

On other stack exchange sites, I think there is a serious problem with non-voting. If no one up votes then no one gets rep and no one get privileges and no one feels like coming back after a short while except for the most extreme users.

I have seen other sites where it was normal to give a +1 if it was their first post to "get them started".

Accumulating rep is part of the allure of participating. It would be interesting to see a side by side comparison of the two sites in respect to their user return rate.

These are the two extremes. I think Christianity.StackExchange is somewhere in the middle. I personally feel like I don't vote enough sometimes, and I think the problem is related to a warped sense that by giving them something I am loosing something (just like paying for something with money), so I end up having to tell myself that it doesn't cost me anything a little more than I would probably admit.

On the whole, I think voting as much as possible would be a good thing for the site. Up and down voting. If it already has 40 ups and you think it is a good post then up it to 41. Why not? It's a good post. If is it pretty bad and it has more than -10 down vote it. It only costs you 1 rep point and really bad posts need to be highly discouraged. One thing: show mercy to the new user. I have only down voted a new user when the information was completely false. If a new user's bad post stems from a misunderstanding about the site it really doesn't make sense to down vote it.

Now your title doesn't really match the concern you paint in the body. I think it is pretty obvious that anyone is allowed to vote, but remember that both are earned privileges. Up voting pretty early at 15 rep and down voting after you get a little experience at 125 rep.

Answer (score 0):

I think some users are jealous about others and not voting. They just want to get points but not want to give.

I think some users still don't know the importance of their votes. They just read and read, accumulating all the knowledge but not helping back.

Another point is that, I vote only when I feel like voting. There is always something in the post which motivates me to vote. The reason could be anything, I can't actually explain it. In short, I vote when I want to vote.

I think it also depends on the mood of the day. When you are in bad mood you are not reading it carefully and there is also less possibility of motivation.

Comment: I understand your position, I often do not vote on a question or answer, at first reading, and some not at all if I cannot answer or for some other reason am unable to fairly evaluate them. I do however reread most questions two or more times before giving my vote. I often get a differing impression on the second or sometimes subsequent readings. I want to be fair to the one asking the question or giving the answer, and find that my first impression is sometimes wrong. I also like to believe that those are put forth out of real concern and not frivolous. I do try to vote on most questions.